# Passing Django Model to Template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a little problem which I can't seem to get my head around. It seems like a very trivial thing but I just can't figure it out. Essentially what I'm trying to do is to create a `Project` model which holds information on a certain project and then have another model called `Link` which holds the name of the link such as 'Get Program' or 'Download Release' and have a URLField which holds the URL for those links and is child of `Project`.

So far my `models.py` is as below:

```
from django.db import models

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_description(self):
        return self.description

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Link(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.URLField()

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Problem is in my `views.py` I want to be able to pass Projects object so I can iterate over them and display all links for each project including the project objects fields such as name and description. So far I've done:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Project, Link

def projects_index(request):

    projects = Project.objects.all()
    links = Link.objects.all()

    context = {
        'projects': projects,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects.html', context)
```

Comment: What does the rest of the view function look like?

Comment: @JackEvans I've updated the views.py in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your template `projects.html` you should be able to loop over the Links for each project with

```
{% for project in projects %}
  {% for link in project.link_set.all %}
      {{ link }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great! that did the trick, I can't believe it was within the loops. I feel stupid :/

Comment: No problem you might want to follow along with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something if you get stuck in future

Comment: Does the project.`link_set.all` get all objects related to that instance of a model? so as an example If I had an object called morse, and I had links that were connected to morse, everything that is related to morse will be displayed?

Comment: Yes but each addtional {{ link.morse.thing }} will result in another duplicate Database Query. If you want to fetch all the related objects at once without duplicating queries you'll need to use `select_related()` and `prefetch_related()` as specified here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 0):

You really should do the tutorial.

```
for project in projects:
    for link in project.link_set.all:
        <...>
```

Add a `related_name="links"` to your foreign key, and the inner loop can be

```
for link in project.links:
```